Не добавляется запись в таблицу БД aiosqlite
Я создаю бота на aiogram. Мне нужно сохранять информацию о пользователях. Я решил использовать не sqlite3, а aiosqlite потому, что он асинхронный, как и aiogram.
Вот код хэндлера:
@all_router.message(Command('start'))
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    load_dotenv()
    kb = None
    if message.from_user.id == int(os.getenv('ADMIN_ID')):
       kb = admin_keyboard
    else: 
       kb = reply_menu_keyboard
       users = Users()
       await users.add_user(message.from_user.id)
       await message.answer(await start_text(message.from_user.username), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kb)

А вот код метода в классе, реализующем CRUD:
async def start(self) -> None:
    async with aiosql.connect(self.path) as con:
        request = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                      user_telegram_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                      status TEXT NOT NULL)'''
        await con.execute(request)

async def add_user(self, uid: int) -> None:
    '''The method adds a user into the table'''
    await self.start()
    async with aiosql.connect(self.path) as con:
        cursor = await con.cursor()
        request = 'INSERT INTO users(user_telegram_id, status) VALUES(?, ?)'
        await cursor.execute(request, (uid, 'member'))

Однако, когда бы я не запускал команду /start, ничего не происходит! Запись не добавляется в БД, но ошибок тоже никаких нет. Без понятия, что может быть не так.
Уже давно использую sqlite3, но в нем ошибок такого плана никогда не было.
Очень нужна помощь
